# ${\lim}_{a \to \infty} {\int}_{a}^{a+1} \frac{x}{x+\ln(x)} |\sin(x\pi)|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to ask the following questions about "The problem", below from the following perspectives;

- (1) Does this limiting value exist?
- (2) What is this limiting value, if exist?

**The problem;**

> $${\lim}_{a \to \infty} {\int}_{a}^{a+1} \frac{x}{x+\ln(x)} |\sin(x\pi)|dx$$

The above "The problem" is my modified version of a problem (Henceforth referred to as the "Original Problem") introduced in a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_mDB2V2z-0&t=625s) video (In Japanese). The "Original Problem" is as follows .

**Original Problem**

> $${\lim}_{a \to \infty} {\int}_{a}^{a+1} \frac{x}{x+\ln(x)} dx$$

The "Original Problem" is an entrance exam problem of the [University of Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Tokyo), Japan.
The answer to the "Original Problem" is;
$${\lim}_{a \to \infty} {\int}_{a}^{a+1} \frac{x}{x+\ln(x)} dx=1 .$$

The essence of the solution to the "Original Problem" is that the
integrand is constant in the limit;　At the $a→∞$ limit, the problem is just integrating $y=1$ over an interval of length $1$. Note that,
$$ {\lim}_{a \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+\ln(x)} =1 .$$

The problem is also probably that in the $a→∞$ limit, the problem is just integrating $|y=sin(xπ)|$ over an interval of length $1$. However, it seems that evaluation methods such as the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), which were available in the original, cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

For large values of $a$, your integral behaves like $\int_a^{a+1}|\sin(\pi x)| dx$.

Indeed: For $a\geq 1$, $$
\left |\int_{a}^{a+1} |\sin(x\pi)|dx-\int_{a}^{a+1} \frac{x}{x+\ln x} |\sin(x\pi)|dx\right|= \int_{a}^{a+1} \frac{\ln x}{x+\ln x} |\sin(x\pi)|dx
\leq \frac{\ln (a+1)}{a+\ln a}$$
and the right-hand side goes to zero as $a\rightarrow +\infty$.
Since  $$\int_a^{a+1}|\sin(\pi x)dx |=\frac 2 \pi$$ the answer is: The value exists and it's $\frac 2 \pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how to calculate $\lim \frac{\ln (a+1)}{a+\ln a}$?
Using  [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)
$\lim \frac{\ln (a+1)}{a+\ln a}=\lim \frac{1/(a+1)}{1+1/a} =\lim  1/a$, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Yes. Or you can show that $\ln x \leq \sqrt{x}$ by studying $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}-\ln x$.

Comment: @Stefan Lafon　Thank you for your comment. Do you mean to differentiate the following g(x) with respect to x and find the approximate shape of the graph of g(x),am I right?
$g(x);=\sqrt{x}-ln(x)$

Comment: Yes, by differentiating, you can show that $g$ has a global minimum at $x=4$ and that the minimum is $\geq 0$.